# Input Field Visibility based on Profiles in VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, profile, dynamic-visualforce

I have Created a VF page to display the data in a table, based on the Search which will be given in the input Text box.I need to make the text box visible only for the admin profile and make it hidden for Salesperson Profiles so that only the assigned search will be displayed as such.Kindly help me solve this with a solution or sample codes if any.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **!$Profile** global variable to access current user’s profile, combined with **disabled** attribute on the apex:inputText component:

```
<apex:inputText value="{!inputValue}" id="inp1" disabled="{$Profile.Name != 'Admin'}"/>
```

For more info, check the documentation:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_profile.htm
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inputText.htm

Comment: I think you missed an exclamation mark there:
`disabled="{!$Profile.Name != 'Admin'}"`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the inputField, set the field level security and that should help you to achieve your requirement outofbox

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Testing_CRUD_and_FLS_Enforcement

Refer the above doc link where the concept and code is explained on how to handle with visualforce render or apex describe